# Have Stormtroopers ever been able to fly before The Rise Of Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-rise-of-skywalker

According a to [a review](https://www.nationalreview.com/2019/12/movie-review-star-wars-the-rise-of-skywalker-disappointing/) of *The Rise of Skywalker*:

> Stormtroopers come after the rebel fighters, this time with a new skill: “They can fly?” someone marvels. Yes, they can fly. Like clay pigeons.

Have Stormtroopers ever been able to fly before *The Rise of Skywalker*, whether in Disney Canon, or the expanded universe?

Comment: Does this require spoiler tags?

Comment: it's in the trailer for goodness sake

Comment: @NKCampbell some people actively avoid even trailers and teasers for a release like this

Comment: then they would probably do well to avoid questions with RoS as a tag then ;) @HorusKol

Comment: @NKCampbell and when the spoiler is in the question title and blurb on the index page?

Comment: I didn't make the title edit - when I made my comments @HorusKol - the title still said [spoiler] and I was specifically addressing the spoiler markup in the question. But yes - you can modify how the home page displays by exluding certain tags. So even if there is a spoiler in the title, if it's tagged appropriately and you truly care about avoiding spoilers, you can. It's how I never see game-of-thrones or fan-fiction questions

Comment: Wraiths! Wraiths on wings!

Answer (score 14):

Yes and they are known as [Jumptroopers](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jumptrooper). They've appeared a few times before with one of the most well known cases being in the new *Star Wars: Battlefront* games. We also see them in *Star Wars Rebels*, for example, in Season 3 Episode 13, "Ghosts of Geonosis":

Comment: but... but... but both Rebels and Imperials call them _Rocket_ Troopers in that clip...

Comment: @gowenfawr Aye, either renamed or just a mistake in the episode... or just synonymous.

Comment: Battlefront had jetpack troopers (Republic) and jump troopers (Empire) alike. The both worked differently. The jetpack ones worked just as Jango and Boba's jetpacks worked. Whereas jump troopers were more of a straight up launch to a high point then quick descent.

Comment: There's also appearances in legends. I recall fighting flying stormtroopers in the *Force Unleashed* games.

Answer (score 4):

Additionally in the clone wars episodes, as seen in S1,E7, clones also wore jet packs for missions where stealth was required, or they could not get in with a LAAT. So it makes sense that the technology would carry over to new factions, and be improved upon.